# How to host Jekyll static website on Apache2 web server

Tags: jekyll

I have made a static website using Jekyll. I also have hosted it in github. Can I host it in apache2 server?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Basically yes. You need to copy the _site folder gernerated by jekyll build to your apache installation.